Какой знак поставил в предложении Д. Хармс?
Это про Д. Хармса:
В своих записных книжках поэт писал: На замечание: «Вы написали с ошибкой»(?) ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании».
 В школе Даниил Хармс получал двойки по русскому языку. А в своих 
 стихотворениях он пропускал запятые, употреблял неправильные падежи. 
 Исправлять неточности Хармс не хотел — как и Достоевский, спорил из-за 
 них с корректорами и редакторами. 

Какой знак поставил Хармс? Неизвестно. Грамотные люди никак не могут выбрать, они пишут: запятую, запятую и тире или ничего.
А как правильно? И какое здесь правило?

«Новый мир» за февраль 1992 г. на стр. 215 воспроизводит это место у Хармса с точкой:

На замечание: «Вы написали с ошибкой». Ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании».

Для поэта или писателя важнее формальной пунктуации могут быть паузы и интонации, задаваемые знаками. Двоеточие здесь задаёт паузу перед прямой речью, а точка показывает, что прямая речь звучит утвердительно.
На самом деле, ни двоеточие перед текстом замечания, ни какой-либо знак после него в данном случае не нужны.
Переформулируем для наглядности:

На замечание о написании с ошибкой ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании».

Или ещё нагляднее:

На такое замечание ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании»

Мы видим, что никаких знаков здесь не нужно. Следовательно, если не учитывать авторскую пунктуацию Хармса, фразу можно было бы записать следующим образом:

На замечание «Вы написали с ошибкой» ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании».

Здесь работает следующее правило:

если прямая речь непосредственно включается в авторское предложение в качестве его члена, то она заключается в кавычки, знаки же препинания ставятся по условиям авторского предложения: Сказав Гричмару фразу «Легкой жизни не бывает, есть лишь легкая смерть», Крымов поймал на себе беспокойный, предупреждающий взгляд Стишова (Бонд.).

Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина. — М.: Эксмо, 2006. — 480 с.

Согласен! Никакого знака перед текстом замечания, ни после него не нужно.

Комментарий к ответу
Прелестно!  Спасибо за информацию! Голос от меня.
Итак, у Хармса была точка... То-то наши литераторы никак не могут правильно записать текст, а ведь они грамотные, не то что он)) А я-то думала: почерк у Хармса неразборчивый, что ли?
Тем любопытнее!
Отметим, что изменять текст никто не стал, зачем же мы будем делать? Тем более что это Хармс, гений абсурда! Нам нужен по возможности подлинный Хармс, поэтому оба двоеточия сохраняем.
А дальше вопрос: какова грамматика? Первая цитата использована в качестве определения (замечание какое?), и здесь явное интонационное предупреждение, обозначенное двоеточием.
Нестандартный вариант, который требует такого же нестандартного решения: нужен ли знак и какой знак после этой цитаты, если уж мы поставили двоеточие? Интонационно там пробелом не обойдешься, отсюда такие эксперименты со знаками. Надо найти это решение и привязать к какому-нибудь правилу.
Иак, вопрос остается в силе:
На замечание: «Вы написали с ошибкой» (?) ответствуй: «Так всегда выглядит в моём написании».
